# Visualization of Purchase Categorization and Trend Analysis in Power BI for Multiple Factories

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have an issue that I'd like to solve in Power BI. We work with around 200 factories, and the majority of our purchases come from just a few of them. I'd like to visualize that we have a tail of factories with lower purchase values. I would like to categorize the factories into, for example, four different groups (quartiles?) and then display this in a stacked column chart with the groups on the X-axis and the stacks representing purchase values. In the tooltip, I'd like to include the number of factories. Additionally, in a separate chart, I'd like to show the trend of each group from the previous year. Do you have any suggestions on how to accomplish this task?

Comment: Sounds like you know exactly what you are after. You need to try step by step then ask for help when you need it. Start with your data and your data model. You will need a Date (Calendar) table, a Factory table, and a Purchases Fact table to get you started.